# C#. Как выводить из папки хранящие в ней другие папки

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать так что бы при указания пути к папки на консоль выводилась ее содержимое.
А именно выводились другие папки которые в ней хранятся. Но уже как 3 часа вожусь с этим и не могу так сделать. Может кто небудь подскажет?

Я только смог выводить подкаталог. К примеру у меня есть папка, в ней храниться еще 3 папки. Дак вот, когда я пишу путь к главной папки, то в консоль выводиться только одна содержимая папка с различными файлами. Но я не знаю как сделать так что бы выводились все папки и их содержимое. Наверное вы поняли.

Вот код который я написал:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("путь к папке");
        string firstInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Directory.Exists(firstInput))
        {
            string[] potcatalogues = Directory.GetDirectories(firstInput);
            foreach (string catalog in potcatalogues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(catalog);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-getdirectories

Comment: Вам нужно получить все папки из выбранной папки? В т.ч. вложенные?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекурсивный поиск это называется

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"C:\Source\ConsoleApp1";
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    ScanDirectory(path);
}

static void ScanDirectory(string path, int depth = 0)
{
    foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', depth) + Path.GetFileName(dir));
        ScanDirectory(dir, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
C:\Source\ConsoleApp1
.vs
-ConsoleApp1
--DesignTimeBuild
--v16
--v17
ConsoleApp1
-bin
--x64
---Debug
----net6.0-windows
-----runtimes
------unix
-------lib
--------net6.0
------win
-------lib
--------net6.0
-obj
--x64
---Debug
----net6.0-windows
-----ref
-----refint
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл и чуть подправил код по первой же почти ссылке. Как вы искали 3 часа - не совсем понятно. Хорошим тоном будет так же оставлять в вопросе "попытки" того, что вы сделали и что у вас не получилось. Делается это для того, чтобы отвечающие люди понимали, что вы попытались и вам нужна помощь для решения NNN проблемы.

Для получения путей до файлов:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var files = GetFolderFiles();
    foreach (string file in files)
        Console.WriteLine(file);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static string[] GetFolderFiles()
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog choofdlog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        return choofdlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(choofdlog.SelectedPath)
            ? Directory.GetFiles(choofdlog.SelectedPath)
            : default;
    }
}
```

Методы класса Directory - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-6.0

Для получения путей до папок Directory.GetDirectories(choofdlog.SelectedPath)

Comment: Имхо, `FolderBrowserDialog` - лишнее усложнение ответа. Ещё и `[STAThread]`. У автора явно консольная программа.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `<UseWindowsForms>` еще надо бы указать, да.

Comment: Если что, то да, у меня консольно приложение. Прошу прощение что не написал об этом. 
А так спасибо всем кто хотел помочь! А так я уже разобрался.